# Updating elements does not work

Tags: d3.js

I have code that should create a set of divs according to data and highlights every time the next element is added. However, this does not work.

```
activeSymbolIndex = activeSymbolIndex + 1 % symbols.length;

var container = d3.select("#symbols-container");

var numbers = container
    .selectAll(".quote-container")
    .data(symbols);

var containers = numbers
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("quote-container", true);
containers
    .append("div")
    .classed("quote-change-numbers", true)
    .style("color", function (d) { return d.PercentColor; })
    .style("background-color", function (d, i) { return i == activeSymbolIndex ? "white" : "transparent"; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.Percent; });
containers
    .append("div")
    .classed("quote-name-text", true)
    .text(function (d) { return d.LongDescription; });

numbers
    .exit()
    .remove();
```

When i run this code for the first time it works jsut fine and produces:

```
<div class="quote-container">
    <div class="quote-change-numbers" style="color: rgb(65, 183, 143); background-color: white;">0.20% 0</div>
    <div class="quote-name-text">E-Mini S&amp;P 500, Jun 13</div>
</div>
<div class="quote-container">
    <div class="quote-change-numbers" style="color: rgb(94, 186, 171); background-color: transparent;">0.13% 1</div>
    <div class="quote-name-text">E-mini NASDAQ 100, Jun 13</div>
</div>
```

First element has white back color as expected.

When i run this code second time i expect the second element to have white back color. However, nothing is changed. Is there a problem with my code?

Comment: What is the initial value of `activeSymbolIndex`? Are you sure about the update rule `activeSymbolIndex = activeSymbolIndex + 1 % symbols.length`? It seems like you may have forgotten about brackets there.

Comment: yes that works not as expected but just fine. It increases. At first step it is 0, at second step it is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run:

```
var containers = numbers
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("quote-container", true);
```

you're assigning to `containers` the result of `numbers.enter()`, which is just the nodes that were created.

So, when you later run:

```
containers
    .append("div")
    .classed("quote-change-numbers", true)
    .style("color", function (d) { return d.PercentColor; })
    .style("background-color", function (d, i) { return i == activeSymbolIndex ? "white" : "transparent"; })
```

this only gets called on those same, entering nodes –– not on any updating nodes. That's why the color never changes.

You'll want to do this with `numbers`

```
numbers
  .select("quote-change-numbers") // NOTE: this uses select –– not selectAll
  .style("background-color", function (d, i) { return i == activeSymbolIndex ? "white" : "transparent"; })
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. may be you can suggest what shall be changed in my code? I cannot run numbers.style() since i want to assigne style not to parent container but to the first child div.

Comment: I wanted doing that in one go. You suggest having additional "loop" throguh all divs. I can do this indeed. But i saw a buchn of d3js examples when the do not have such additional code and it works the way i have it. The only difference is that they do not need changing child divs and deal only wit parents.

Comment: @Evgeniy I don't understand what you mean. Here's how I see it: At this point you have code that ONLY runs on elements bound to **new** data (where you update `containers`). You currently have no code that affects updating elements, which is what you need for updating the bg color. So how do you expect to avoid calling methods on `numbers`?

Comment: Looks like i am missing something. My understanding is that when you run select().data().enter().append(), it: 1. itterates over all existing nodes executing code, 2. adds missing nodes. You are saying that if number of nodes is not changes then no code willl be executed.

Comment: Number 1 is not correct. Anything you call on the selection returned by `enter()` has no effect on existing nodes. And, if number of nodes doesn't change, then the selection returned by `numbers.enter()` (which you're assigning to `container`) is an empty selection, so calling methods like `style()` on this selection does nothing. Meanwhile –– even if the number of nodes stays the same –– the full, "updating" selection (`numbers` in your case) is **not** empty, so calling `style()` or `select()` on it actually affects all the nodes.